# How do i make use for loop so that after it has ran my first list then it will continue on with my second for loop with another list

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

```
for i in range (len(outputList)):
    worksheet.write(i+1, 0, outputList[i][0])
    worksheet.write(i+1, 3, outputList[i][1], center)
    if outputList[i][2] == "Passed":
        worksheet.write(i+1, 1, outputList[i][2], passed) 

    elif outputList[i][2] == "Failed":
        worksheet.write(i+1, 1, outputList[i][2], failed)

        if outputList[i][3] == "Severe":
            worksheet.write(i+1, 2, outputList[i][3], severe)

        if outputList[i][3] == "Moderate":
            worksheet.write(i+1, 2, outputList[i][3], moderate)

        if outputList[i][3] == "Minor":
            worksheet.write(i+1, 2, outputList[i][3], minor)
```

Hi i am trying to input values into my automated generated excel using python and i was thinking after inserting the values into my excel from the for loop above, i want to insert values below with values from another list but how do i do that? Code for other for loop below:

```
for i in range (len(passList)):
            worksheet.write(i+1, 0, passList[i][0])
            worksheet.write(i+1, 3, passList[i][1], center)    
            if passList[i][2] == "Passed":
                worksheet.write(i+1, 1, passList[i][2], passed)     
                if passList[i][3] == "None":
                    worksheet.write(+1, 2, passList[i][3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have properly understood what you want to do, something like this might do the job:

```
for i, item in enumerate(outputList, start=1):
    worksheet.write(i, 0, item[0])
    # ...

for i, item in enumerate(passList, start=len(outputList+1)):
    worksheet.write(i, 0, item[0])
    # ...
```

I’m using the built-in `[enumerate]`[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to avoid having to type `outputList[i]` a gazillion times, and its optional `start` argument to adjust the numbering to the worksheet.

**Edit**

If you want do to exactly the same thing to both lists, you could just concatenate them from the start:

```
for i, item in enumerate(outputList + passList, start=1):
    # ...
```

Obviously, this will use some extra memory for the concatenated list. If this is unacceptable, you could use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) instead of concatenating them.